# How to get Holo Light theme working in my Xamarin application

Tags: android, xamarin, android-theme

I'm trying to get my app to use the Holo.Light theme. I've created a custom theme for Holo and put it in

**Resourses\values-v11\FsmTheme.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="FsmTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

I've also created one for older versions and put it in

**Resourses\values\FsmTheme.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="FsmTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then I added it to my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="001" android:versionName="001" package="futurestate.app.droid">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <application android:label="FutureState App Demo" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" Theme="@style/FsmTheme" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

I'm not sure what else I would need to do to get the theme to take in the app.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The breakdown is on this line.

```
<application android:label="FutureState App Demo" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" Theme="@style/FsmTheme" />
```

Some of the tutorials out there show

```
Theme="@style/ThemeName"
```

but you should actually structure it the same as the rest of the element

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeName"
```

So the final structure will read

```
<application android:label="FutureState App Demo" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:theme="@style/FsmTheme" />
```

Comment: @BrettD's answer should be the accepted one, as it was given long before you answered your own question. it's also more comprehensible

Comment: @thumbmunkeys his answer is also correct, but my issue was that I was putting the incorrect values in the xml. I was reading documentation that was leading me down an incorrect path. Also, several hours is not "long before". Brett is right, but I (at the time) was not willing to use the attribute approach. I like to keep things pure and contained, which includes putting the values in the manifest.

Answer (score 15):

You can use Attributes to modify values in the AndroidManifest.xml, for example this changes the theme to holo light:

```
[Activity(
    Label = "Foobar",
    MainLauncher = true,
    Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
)]
public class MainActivity : Activity { ... }
```

You can also do this at the Application level.

But for your specific problem, it seems that you are naming your style files `FsmTheme.xml`. That is incorrect. You must name any styling resources `styles.xml`, so if you rename your files to `Resources/values/styles.xml` and `Resources/values-v11/styles.xml` everything should work as expected.

Comment: This ought to be the accepted answer, as it really is the "Xamarin way" of solving the problem.