# change background color of toolbaritems from codebehind

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to change background color of toolbaritems from code behind.

```html
 <ContentPage.ToolbarItems Name="ToolBarItems" BackgroundColor="#1FBED6">
    <ToolbarItem Name="Menu1" Order="Secondary" Text="Test1"/>
    <ToolbarItem Name="Menu2" Order="Secondary" Text="Test2"/>
    <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Icon="Cart.png"/>
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either need to do platform specific code or you can use the more general approach of using the `NavigationPage` methods.

So if you are using a `NavigationPage`, then you can do something like this:

```
NavigationPage navPage = new NavigationPage {
    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#1FBED6"),
    BarTextColor       = Color.FromHex("#000000")
}
```

If you wanted to make the `BarBackgroundColor` change when visiting a different page, then you would just keep a global reference to the `NavigationPage`. I keep it in the `App.cs` class.

If you would rather go with a native approach, on iOS you could use the Appearance API and just add the styles to your AppDelegate.cs file, more info [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_the_appearance_api/#Setting_Appearance_Properties).

Then on Android, you would want to mess around with the theme, more info on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382467/how-to-get-holo-light-theme-working-in-my-xamarin-application).